# SQL "Insert" in VBA code

Tags: sql, excel, vba, postgresql, insert

There is an issue (Type mismatch error) in the code below in the line:
Action = ....

I try to use Sql INSERT INTO to copy arrays from Excel and paste it into PostgreSQl database.

```
Sub UploadToDatamart2()

'Defining connection objects
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("AVON DICTIONARY").Activate

'Opening the ODBC connection
cnn.Open "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};DSN=postgres;Server=XXX;Port=5432;UID=YYY;PWD=ZZZ;Database=hurtownia;READONLY=0;PROTOCOL=6.4;FAKEOIDINDEX=0;SHOWOIDCOLUMN=0;ROWVERSIONING=0;SHOWSYSTEMTABLES=1"

'Find the last row
With ActiveSheet
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Picking up cell values
    Category = .Range("A3:A" & LRow).Value
    segment = .Range("B3:B" & LRow).Value
    brand = .Range("C3:C" & LRow).Value
End With

'Defining and executing SQL insert
Action = "INSERT INTO temp.avon_dictionary_test" & " VALUES ('{" & Category & "}','{" & segment & "}','{" & brand & "}')"
Result = cnn.Execute(Action)

cnn.Close
End Sub
```

I would be glad if anyone could help

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.  It will help in debugging issues like this. You need to add `Dim Action As String` and change your execute line to `cnn.Execute(Action)`. This won't return a recordset.

Comment: I have added: Option Explicit - on the top, also: Dim Category As Variant
Dim segment As Variant, Dim brand As Variant. Amend this: Dim LRow As Long and replace Result = cnn.Execute(Action) with  cnn.Execute (Action). And still the same error

Comment: Dim Action As String - I have added this also but still gets the issue

Comment: Add this just before the `Action = ` line  - `Debug.Print TypeName(Category), TypeName(segment), TypeName(brand)`  What is the output in the Immediate pane?

Comment: Here is what immediate window shows: Variant()     Variant()     Variant()

Comment: In the postgre's table, all these columns (category, segment, brand) have a "character varying" data type. if its matter

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning range to `Category`, `segment` and `brand` variables. Once a range is assigned to a variable, it converts the variable from variant to an array (unless the variable is specifically declared otherwise). Now that the variables are arrays, you have to reference the item (i.e. `Category(0)`). Try referencing the item in your `Action =` statement

Answer (score 0):

Category, Segment and Brand are 2D-arrays, you can't concatenate them in a string like that. You first need to transpose them to 1D-Array, then use Join to build a string from them:

First replace

```
Category = .Range("A3:A" & LRow).Value
segment = .Range("B3:B" & LRow).Value
brand = .Range("C3:C" & LRow).Value
```

with

```
Category = Application.Transpose(.Range("A3:A" & LRow).Value)
segment = Application.Transpose(.Range("B3:B" & LRow).Value)
brand = Application.Transpose(.Range("C3:C" & LRow).Value)
```

Then replace

```
Action = "INSERT INTO temp.avon_dictionary_test" & " VALUES ('{" & Category & "}','{" & segment & "}','{" & brand & "}')"
```

with

```
Action = "INSERT INTO temp.avon_dictionary_test" & " VALUES ('{" & Join(Category, ",") & "}','{" & Join(segment, ",") & "}','{" & Join(brand, ",") & "}')"
```

[Transpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196261.aspx) will change the (1 to LRow, 1 to 1) arrays to plain (1 to LRow) arrays.

[Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264098.aspx) will concatenate the values from the arrays in a string separated by the delimiter (here ",").

Comment: Thanks Vincent. Now I get "Invalid procedure call or argument" error in the line Action =...  In my test file LRow = 4000, Is this too many for this procedure?

Comment: Since your data are in row, I thin you need to transpose your array before using Join.

Comment: hmm, so I am wondering is this a good idea to use COPY instead of INSERT INTO [link] (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)? I feel weak in sql so that's I am asking

Comment: Still not working with Transpose as in my edited answer?

Comment: If I transpose data I will get 4000 column. What if my data reach 100k?

Comment: Well, I don't know if there is limitation on the OCDB connection, but I think Strings are limited to 2^31 characters, so there is some room. You can also try to insert data in smaller blocks (by groups of 1k rows?) with a for loop.

Comment: Vincent, I followed your solution and finally import sth to my postgres table. It is still imperfect but I think need slight adjustement....

Comment: ...This is how my postgres table looks now [link](http://oi67.tinypic.com/2rcpqbk.jpg). It has one row only and the JOIN values are all inside a cell